# Не полностью копируется текст из одного текстового редактора в другой

Tags: java, поток-ввода

Код:

```
package ВводВывод;

import java.io.*;

public class CopyFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int i;

    if (args.length != 2) {
        System.out.println("Нужно два файла!");
        return;
    }

    try (FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
         FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[1]))
    {
        do {
            i = fin.read();
            if (fin.read() != -1) fos.write(i);
        } while (i != -1);
    } catch (IOException exc) {
        System.out.println("Ошибка ввода-вывода: " + exc);
    }
  }
}
```

Два текстовых файла. В файле `qqq.txt` находится текст: `Java The Best`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Терминал ввожу следующее сообщение:

`Z:\Java1\out\production\Java>java ВводВывод.CopyFile ВводВывод\qqq.txt ВводВывод\qqq1.txt`

После этого в `qqq1.txt` появляется вот такой текст: `Jv h e`

То есть он копирует символы обрывками.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i = fin.read();
if (fin.read() != -1)
```

Читаешь дважды. Один раз, потом второй и только второй раз пишешь в другой файл

```
 i = fin.read();
 if(i!=-1) fos.write(i);
```

Comment: Serhii Dikobrazko, Все заработало!

Comment: @Новичок можно галочку у ответа? мы тут не бесплатно работаем :)